# Lighting Candles when eating Out on Friday Night

Tags: halacha, shabbat, candle-lighting, hachnasat-orchim-guests

If one is going out to eat (such as at a simcha), should Shabbos candles be lit at home or at the hall? I heard that some rabbis do not allow candles to be lit at the hall in the shul but instruct whomever is making the simcha to advise their guests to light at their host's home where they will be sleeping.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you get good answers, and that you also look around and see what else around here is of interest, perhaps starting with our dozens of other [tag:candle-lighting] questions. Please consider [registering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Also, I suggest [editing your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) to give yourself a name!

Answer (score 3):

[Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/sh/ht/fn/48965051.html) says one should light at home, so long they will remain lit until they return - or alternatively stay home until it is dark before going out to eat.

> What if we won't be home for dinner Friday night? Light your candles
>   at home if you will be returning to sleep there, as long as they will
>   still be burning when you return home. Otherwise, light your candles
>   at home and stay until after dark before leaving for your dinner
>   "out." (If you are afraid of candles burning unsupervised, simply
>   light them in a sink that you won't be using during Shabbat!)

[Rav Doniel Schreiber](http://etzion.org.il/en/lighting-shabbat-candles-part-2) says that one should light in their own home, however if that is not an option they can light in their hosts home.

> Laws of Candle lighting When One is not in His or Her Own Household
>
> Eating Out   One who eats at a friend's house but sleeps at home is
>   not considered to have left one's own household.  If a couple eats the
>   Friday night meal at a friend's house they do not fulfill their
>   obligation of nerot Shabbat with their hosts.  They must light their
>   own candles..  Similarly, children who are benei mitzva ate the Friday
>   night meal at a friend's house, but will return home to sleep, fulfill
>   their obligation of nerot Shabbat with the candles which were lit in
>   their own home.  (Radiance of Shabbat, pp. 8-12, in the name of Rav
>   Moshe Feinstein zt"l.)   If one is not eating at home, where should
>   the Shabbat candles be lit?  Their  hosts have already fulfilled the
>   primary obligation of nerot Shabbat when they lit in their household. 
>   Therefore, it is preferable that the guests light in their own home to
>   fulfill their own primary obligation.  However, some benefit from the
>   light of the candles must be derived before the candles burn out.  If
>   lighting in their own home is not an option, the wife may light in
>   their host's home even with a berakha since she has contributed
>   secondary light to her host's household (Radiance of Shabbat pp. 11-12
>   in the name of Rav Moshe Feinstein zt"l).

Answer (score 2):

I asked a notable Orthodox Rav in the 5 Towns area, this question on Shabbat.

He stated that, technically, one can do it either way. His explanation.

The problem that often occurs is that the host's or eating place is not walking distance from your home. Once, you light the candles, you have accepted Shabbat, so you cannot drive. Thus, people drive to the shul or host's home, and once they arrive, light candles there.

The rav explained that another option is to light *al t'nai* - on condition - that one is lighting now, but states that he has not yet accepted Shabbat restrictions until the time for Shabbat has arrived. I don't understand all the details about this, but, I gather the concept is that this would allow one to light at home yet still drive to shul.

Comment: The question is not about accepting Shabbos, but about where (at home or at the host's home) should candles be lit when one eats elsewhere but will be returning home.

Comment: I think I answer the question in explaining that the places where you can light depends on where or how you accept Shabbat.

Comment: The question also involves if you can light at home when eating out even when it does not matter where you accept Shabbos. For example, eating next door but not returning home until the candles have burnt out. Of course, this assumes that one puts the candelabra in the sink or uses closed bulbs with oil for safety.

Comment: Do you have more info or sources on lighting at shul? I've only heard about lighting where one will sleep or where one will eat. I'm wondering if it's OK to light at shul if I would neither sleep nor eat there.

Answer (score -2):

It has become standard practice (and as such it attains the full strength of Jewish law) for women to accept Shabbat with the kindling of Shabbat candles, unless the woman specifically had in mind while lighting the candles that she wishes to delay the acceptance of Shabbat for a short period of time.1

This unspoken stipulation is often employed by women who wish to drive to the synagogue for services after they light the Shabbat candles—especially on Yom Kippur eve when traditionally all women attend services.

Chabad.org

Comment: Since you cite chabad.org, you should put in the actual link and the relevant quotation. In any case, that does not answer the question.

Comment: Not very relevant, but I'm pretty sure it's more traditional for women to attend services Yom Kippur morning; I think polishe Chasidic women don't  go for kol nidrei. Please someone correct me if you know otherwise